# google maps (com.google.android.maps) crashes application

Tags: android, google-maps, crash

I have been trying to work with google maps in android.
But the application crashes. :(

Here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
   <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="0E8T-qQndWDg8lEScymvQro3kJ1bGlSKLolDE3Q"
    />            
 </LinearLayout>
```

I have included (after ):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and also(after ):

```
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

I am unable to find any error.

Comment: open logcat and paste the logs in your question..

Comment: also the code for your activity, are you extending MapActivity?

Comment: Thanx @aromero that itself solved the prob...
just needed to extend MapActivity instead or Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to extend MapActivity instead of Activity.